# Add markers on Google Map in other Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

How to get access from main activity to fragment? I want to add marker in fragment class with location from recycledview. Object with location data is in ClubBean. I obtained this by interface ClubAdapter.OnClubClickListener:

```
        @Override
        public void onClicked (ClubBean club) {
            ClubBean bean = club;
            Log.d("Name: ", bean.getClubName());
        }
```

Main Activity:

```
  public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoadAllClubsInterface, ClubAdapter.OnClubClickListener {

        private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

        private RecyclerView clubRecycler;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager clubLayoutManager;
        private ArrayList<ClubBean> clubList = new ArrayList<ClubBean>();

        private RecyclerView.Adapter clubAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MyMapFragment()).commit();

            new LoadAllClubs(this).execute(); //load list in background from database

            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            clubRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            clubRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
            clubLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

            clubRecycler.setLayoutManager(clubLayoutManager);

        }

        @Override
        public void finishDataLoad(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> clubs) {
            Iterator<HashMap<String, String>> iterator = clubs.iterator();
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                map = iterator.next();
                clubList.add(new ClubBean(map.get("name"),map.get("localization"), map.get("score")));
            }
            //pass the class that implements your listener as a parameter.
            clubAdapter = new ClubAdapter(clubList, this, this);
            clubRecycler.setAdapter(clubAdapter);
        }

     @Override
        public void onClicked (ClubBean club) {
            ClubBean bean = club;
            Log.d("Name: ", bean.getClubName());
        }

    }
```

My MapFragment Class:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;

    public MyMapFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mMapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if (mMapView != null){
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        LatLng triCity = new LatLng(54.4158773,18.6337789);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(triCity).title("Trojmiasto"));
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(triCity, 11));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The convenient way of communication between Activity and Fragment is via Interface. Here is example code based on your problem:

**Step 1**: Define an interface like this:

```
public interface IFragmentController{
          void passDataToFragmentMethod(String someStringValue);
    }
```

**Step 2**:Implement this Interface into your fragment. Then you will get `passDataToFragmentMethod(String someStringValue)` method in your fragment.

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment implements IFragmentController{


@Override
void passDataToFragmentMethod(String someStringValue){
    // So your logic code here using passed value
}


}
```

**Step 3**: In your Activity just get instance of your fragment and call `passDataToFragmentMethod` method in this way:

```
Fragment mapFragment=new MyMapFragment();
```

and

```
@Override
public void onClicked (ClubBean club) {
 ClubBean bean = club;
 Log.d("Name: ", bean.getClubName());
 mapFragment.passDataToFragmentMethod(bean.getClubName());
 }
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

> The host activity can deliver messages to a fragment by capturing the Fragment instance with findFragmentById(), then directly call the fragment's public methods.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Just define a method in `MyMapFragment` like `addMarkers`, then call it from activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
      public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoadAllClubsInterface, ClubAdapter.OnClubClickListener {

            MyMapFragment mMyFragment;

         @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
                    mMyFragment=new MyMapFragment();
                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,mMyFragment).commit();
        }

 private void addMarkers(){
    //defined this method in Mapfragment
    mMyFragment.addMarkers();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if u have list then

```
For(ClubBean obj:ClubList)
{

// latitude and longitude
double latitude =obj.getLatValue();
double longitude = obj.getLngValue();

// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
}
```